# PHP / IIS - Limit On The Number Of Files That Can Be Uploaded At Once?

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I have a PHP web application which allows the user to add multiple items, and attach a file to be stored with each item.

I am able to attach a file to items 1-19, however it always fails at item number 20.

Additionally, all items in the $_FILES[] array are empty, whereas they are always populated for items 1-19, regardless of whether a file is selected or not.

Is there a limit on how many files may be uploaded in one go on IIS? If so, how do I change this?

NOTE: I am aware there is a limit on the size of uploaded files, however I am nowhere near this limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`php.ini` has a `max_file_uploads` directive which controls how many files can be uploaded at once, and it defaults to 20.

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads